# Form fields not saving to DB: does this have to do with how form parameters are passed for new/create controller methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, rspec-rails

I’m a newbie trying to create a simple Rails (4.2.1) app that allows a user (when logged in >> ‘devise’ gem) to add a post with an image (‘paperclip’ gem).

The form data is not being saved in the DB. I suspect this might have to do with the way the parameters are passed but since I’m new to this, I’m not sure.

It was working — posts were being saved in DB and then displayed on site — until I refactored the form to use @post instead of Post.new (so my view isn’t speaking directly to the model), and then added the 'new' method to the controller, but now the form data is not being saved.

I tried both using and omitting passing in the ‘post_params’ for the 'new' method. When I pass in the params to 'new' method, I get this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: post):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:22:in `post_params'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:18:in `new'
```

As a side note: I left out “multipart: true” in the form because based on the Rails documentation, I understood it was needed only for “form_tag” and not for “form_for” (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

Here is the controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]

  def index
     @post = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    redirect_to '/'
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:caption, :image)
  end
end
```

Here is the form (posts/new.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for @post  do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :caption %>
  <%= f.text_field :caption %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<br><a href=/posts> back to all posts </a>
```

Unfortunately I refactored the form with @post at the same time that I added the image upload to the form; before this, the form was working fine and data was being stored in db and displayed on site correctly (and by "correct" I mean as intended :)

After starting the sever and loading the page locally, I’m not seeing errors that give me clues about saving the form data to the DB. The errors I see are something about missing.png — I’m assuming this is because there is no default image loaded, one called “missing.png”.

```
Started GET "/images/medium/missing.png" for ::1 at 2015-07-14 12:06:59 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/medium/missing.png"):
  actionpack (4.2.1)
lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
```

**Edited here to include Post model:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

This is the DB schema:

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "caption"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
```

My questions are:

— what is the correct way to pass in parameters for the methods ‘create' and ‘new’?

— If this is not in fact the cause of the error, is there anything else in the code given here that might be preventing posts from being saved to DB?

Bonus Question:

The current RSpec failure is also not very detailed (probably speaks to my tests -- yikes).

— Is there a better way to test this? What should a test for this look like? Currently, the only unit tests are for associations and they pass; the section of the feature test that is currently failing is below.

```
  context 'creating posts' do
    scenario 'prompts user to fill out a form, then displays the new post' do
      user_sign_in

      visit '/posts'
      click_link 'add a post'
      fill_in 'Caption', with: 'sunny Saturday'
      attach_file 'post_image', './public/IMG.jpg'
      click_button 'Create Post'
      expect(page).to have_content 'sunny Saturday'
      expect(current_path).to eq '/'
    end
  end
```

Which just confirms what I'm seeing locally.

Failures:

```
  1) posts - creating posts prompts user to fill out a form, then displays the new post
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content 'sunny Saturday'
       expected to find text "sunny Saturday" in "sign out no posts yet add a post"
```

**Edited here with development log details:**

```
Started POST "/posts" for ::1 at 2015-07-14 13:28:20 +0200
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mc4hUr1Kzf4P+EsW09518zUWOUHsldj5cHiIbi427THxti76PG0Yvr+a7/KMHIsgJMln+YugyDdRNOXy4LvDRw==", "post"=>{"caption"=>"new post", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe121b00b30 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/cc/nyvtq7hj62s98br08bcfzg6w0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150714-93392-arzgnw.jpg>, @original_filename="cat1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"cat1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Command :: PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/var/folders/cc/nyvtq7hj62s98br08bcfzg6w0000gn/T/a980d10665f268b0ec6c13ebea43034f20150714-93392-1qoui22.jpg'
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename cat1.jpg (["image/jpeg"]), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
Command :: PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/var/folders/cc/nyvtq7hj62s98br08bcfzg6w0000gn/T/a980d10665f268b0ec6c13ebea43034f20150714-93392-7beczf.jpg'
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename cat1.jpg (["image/jpeg"]), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-07-14 13:28:20 +0200
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts"[0m
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.6ms)
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 26.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started GET "/images/medium/missing.png" for ::1 at 2015-07-14 13:28:20 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/medium/missing.png"):
```

And yes, in the future, I will refactor only after things work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct way to pass in parameters for the methods
>   ‘create' and ‘new’?

Your form looks good for me.

> is there anything else in the code given here that might be preventing
>   posts from being saved to DB?

Your `create` action doesn't save a record.

```
 def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to '/'
  end
```

> The errors I see are something about missing.png — I’m assuming this
>   is because there is no default image loaded, one called “missing.png”.

Right

Comment: Good one. I can't stop my laugh being to know that OP missed it :D

Comment: Thanks Зелёный! This solved part of it: it works now and saves the posts when no image is attached, but once an image is attached, the posts are not saved/displayed. Confirmed this by checking DB tables.

Comment: @Milena please post your `Post` model and a relevant `paperclip` uploader.

Comment: @ Зелёный edited with Post model. What do you mean by "uploader"?

Comment: @Milena ok, so have you a success upload an image to the `public/images` directory? I mean an image file persisted in `public/images` directory?

Comment: @Зелёный no, an image did not persist in the directory :( I did not have an /images directory within /public, but I just added /images to it and tried uploading an image, but the image did not get added to public/images.

Comment: @Milena could you show piece of `log/development.log` file where i can see a relevant request? One tip,  remove the `validates_attachment_content_type` validation and try to upload again

Comment: @Зелёный removed the "validates...type" and got an error: "Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError". The log/development.log file shows -- BEFORE removing validates: Started GET "/images/medium/missing.png" for ::1 at 2015-07-14 13:17:23 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/medium/missing.png"): AND AFTER removing "validates..": 
Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError (Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:13:in `create'

Comment: @Milena i do not work with `paperclip` from some version, it has a required validation. Could you please roll it back and paste a piece of log with request?

Comment: @Зелёный added logs at the end of the original question

Comment: @Milena according your log file, i see `ROLLBACK`, and errors say `Content Type Spoof: Filename cat1.jpg (["image/jpeg"])`, this mean it wanted `*.jpeg` but you pass `*.jpg`. That's your problem. Try rename file `cat1.jpg` to `cat1.jpeg` and upload it again if it's is works, roots of problem in validation.

Comment: @Зелёный Command :: PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin:$PATH; file -b --mime '/var/folders/cc/nyvtq7hj62s98br08bcfzg6w0000gn/T/9428beec5dd65d1b54985661ca3eefca20150714-93392-1sn35n0.jpeg'
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename cat2.jpeg (["image/jpeg"]), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.

Comment: @Зелёный  I'm going to research this error with paperclip validations for a bit. Thank you for looking at it repeatedly :)

Comment: @Milena yep, it's problem in a paperclip validation, try work around of my several answers [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691948/paperclip-image-not-being-added-in-mysql-database/24692152#24692152) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093473/content-type-validation-with-paperclip-fails/25093594#25093594) and use your `google-fu` happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to @Зелёный for pointing out my post's ‘create’ method was missing @post.save.

The form works now and the posts with images are saving to DB and displaying on the site. The issue with the images stemmed from the Paperclip gem.

The following solutions from similar Paperclip issues posted to SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912322/ruby-on-rails-paperclip-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689576/paperclip-error-notidentifiedbyimagemagickerror), fixed the image saving issues:

— downloaded GhostScript

```
brew install gs
```

— added the following code to a file, config/initializers/paperclip_media_type_spoof_detector_override.rb:

```
require 'paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector'

Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/bin'

module Paperclip
  class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
    old_spoofed = instance_method(:spoofed?)

    define_method(:spoofed?) do
      if supplied_file_content_types.count > 0
        old_spoofed.bind(self).()
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end
end
```